# Apple API fsckup: how do I make unsafepointerof 0 a.k.a. NULL / 0x0 in swift?

Tags: ios, swift2, objective-c-swift-bridge

I have a case when parameter should have been UIViewController!
to map from objc properly, but it is, sadly, UIViewController.

This

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController currentVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard unsafeAddressOf(currentVC).hashValue != 0 else { // 31316097 filed with apple
```

feels a bit fragile. hashValue might map to 0 for pointers other than 0x0.
How do I make an unsafe pointer for NULL to compare unsafeAddressOf(currentVC) against?

Swift 2.3 in case it's a typical lets do with for swift 2 but but but we have made it much, much better in swift 3! Kind of answer is required.

Comment: `NULL` doesn't exist in Swift. There's `nil`, which is a shorthand for `Optional<T>.none`.

Answer (score -1):

`currentVC` can't be `nil`. It's not an `Optional` type.

Comment: Indeed, it can not be nil. Swift bridging from obj-c ensures that. However NULL (0x00000000) pointers arrive into that function just fine. Which necessitates the dirty dance outlined in the question rather that simply doing guarded force unwrapping.

Comment: @AntonTropashko That shouldn't be possible. The parameter should be imported into ObjC as `nonnull`

Comment: Oh, I agree 100%. It shouldn't be possible. But it does happen.

Comment: @AntonTropashko What's the function signature of the method once imported into ObjC?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipageviewcontrollerdatasource/1614118-pageviewcontroller?language=objc

Comment: @AntonTropashko Please create a complete, minimal, verifiable example.